# Parse.com operation forbidden when trying to search for username in WPF 8.1 application

Tags: c#, wpf, parse-platform

I've got a program, which would need to see, wheather the user exists or not, but I allways get operation an Operation Forbidden error code.

Here's the part of the code:

```
try
{
    await ParseUser.GetQuery("username").GetAsync(result.ToString());
    textblockstring = "user exists";
}
catch (ParseException e)
{
    if (e.Code == ParseException.ErrorCode.ObjectNotFound)
    {
        textblockstring = "user doesn't exist";
    }
    else
    {
        textblockstring = e.Code.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your wrapping method async ?

Comment: Yes it is. Also, login and signup works, and app appears at parse.com

Comment: https://parse.com/questions/how-to-query-a-parseuser-for-username
this seems like it is a similar problem maybe it is of some help

Comment: Still not working, but since then I tried, and I realized I can't access anything from parse.com with query

Comment: Found what's cousing a problem, I have to add the class first, but still don't know how

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution, here's a working example:
`try
                {
                    var user = ParseUser.Query.WhereEqualTo("username", result.ToString());
                    IEnumerable<ParseObject> resultnumber = await user.FindAsync();
                    if (resultnumber.Count() != 0)
                    {
                        textblockstring = "user exists";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        textblockstring = "user doesn't exist";
                    }
                }
                catch (ParseException e)
                {
                    if (e.Code == ParseException.ErrorCode.ObjectNotFound)
                    {
                        textblockstring = e.Message.ToString();
                        //textblockstring = "user doesn't exist";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        textblockstring = e.Message.ToString();
                    }
                }`

Don't forget to put it in an async cycle